# Possible to affect top ranking unanswered?

Tags: discussion

This question:

[WPF Toolkit Charting and IndependentValueBinding, IndependentValuePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960740/wpf-toolkit-charting-and-independentvaluebinding-independentvaluepath)

Is currently at the top of the unanswered questions in the `WPF` category. That is a mild nuisance, as the original author has fixed the problem and moved on, yet the question remains, but lacking details to answer it.

Can something be done in this case?

Comment: Flag for closure as a problem that cannot be reproduced.

Comment: What's hilarious is that there is a deleted answer to that question that says "As you mentioned in comment above the code has been rewritten. you can submit you answer here. thanks"